# Why are my motors not getting enough power?

Tags: arduino, power, motor, stepper-motor, uln2003

I am a newbie electrical engineering hobbyist who is trying to get four 28BYJ-48 stepper motors to turn for a split flap display project. I managed to get each motor working perfectly well individually but when I tried all four together the motors did not have enough torque to turn the flaps. I do not have a multimeter available to me so I require some intelligence in figuring out the problem.

**My question is: why are my motors not receiving enough power?** Each motor requires 12V to run, I don't know the amperage required and it seems this info is hard to get. Rough estimations online seem to suggest about 250 mA is required per motor but nobody seems sure

Here is the schematic below, I'm using an arduino&ULN203 Driver board to run the steppers I apologize if it is terrible but please know that I am trying my hardest:

If an addition knowledge is needed please do not hesitate to ask for it. Many thanks -KWC

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8zGPK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Slightly tidied up schematic by @Transistor.*

Links:
[Wallwart 12V](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HNV6SBJ)
[Motor+UL2003 Driver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DHLKV9L)
[[image: pics][3]]
[image: pics2]

Comment: Exactly which 'Wallwart 3A 12V' power supply do you have, and which ULN2003 driver board? _"I do not have a multimeter..."_ - time to get one! Please show us a photo of your setup, including _all_ wiring.

Comment: I don't see a +12 connection to your stepper motor but maybe it's in the motor connector. Note how we're able to eliminate a lot of wiring by using GND symbols which instantly show all the ground-referenced points as well as removing a lot of clutter. PSUs are oriented + at top by convention.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Will do give me a minute, to collect the stuff. Although I'm confused on how to answer the which wallwart question, I'll get you the link

Comment: @Transistor yes the its the motor connecter. Oh! Thank you the reason for the GND triangles always mystified me.

Comment: Links to products are up, adding the picture now, there are a lot of wires though and I'm not sure it will be helpful :l

Comment: @BruceAbbott okay pictures are up

Comment: Remember that when turning on, motors require far more current than they do once they're up to speed. I'm talking ten or twenty times their nominal current. It's likely your power supply can't provide this current spike.

Comment: Could be a code problem. Controll  signal for step motor is not simple.

Comment: @user263983 i got the code to work just fine with one and just copy pasted for multiple

Comment: Disconnect two.  Try your code with just two.  They work, it is power not code.

Answer (score 1):

If the motors are turning individually (or under no load) then it is most likely a power\load problem. This results from resistance\inductance in the wires, large loads cause the voltage to drop in the cable especially in switching applications. This voltage drop leads to a loss in power.

1. Get a better power supply (like a bench supply with current and voltage display so you know how much power your design is using).
2. Don't step all the motors at the same time, stagger the stepping so the load on the power supply is distributed.
3. Use a [power bypass capacitor][1] (or several one for each ULN2003 placed next to the inputs of the ULN2003 on the 12V line and ground.
4. Use better wires, smaller gauge wires have a lot of resistance and jumper wire may not have that great of contact resistance. It may be that some of the connections may have more than 100mΩ resistance (or the total resistance from the supply to the motor might exceed 100mΩ with the setup above). 100mΩ will cause a 0.12V drop, 1Ω will be a 1.2V drop which would be a significant loss in power.
   [1]: [https://www.electronicshub.org/bypass-capacitor-tutorial/#:~:text=A%20Bypass%20Capacitor%20is%20usually%20applied%20between%20the,bypasses%20the%20high%20frequency%20components%20of%20power%20supply](https://www.electronicshub.org/bypass-capacitor-tutorial/#:%7E:text=A%20Bypass%20Capacitor%20is%20usually%20applied%20between%20the,bypasses%20the%20high%20frequency%20components%20of%20power%20supply).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused I why I don't have enough power? I think that I have all the things I need to make this work but haven't put them together right. Buying more stuff seems like a waste of money

Comment: @KidWithComputer:   Until you get a meter to measure the current drawn by the motors and the voltages at various points with motors running (or trying to run) you won't know whether or not you have enough power, or where you are losing power.

Comment: @PeterBennett I've had a lot of people tell me that and your probably right, but I'd rather debug for 2 hours then fork over $40

Comment: @KidWithComputer If you're seriously strapped for cash, you can get a cheap piece of junk multimeter for like $5 at a home improvement store. I *strongly* advise against this if you have any way of remotely affording a good $50~$100 meter (Extech's EX505 is a good budget one), but a piece of junk meter is better than no meter. Just don't go sticking a $5 multimeter into a power outlet to measure your mains voltage... And *especially* don't go sticking it in to measure your mains current! (common mistake beginners make that results in blown fuses on good meters and exploded meters on bad ones)

Comment: Even the 'junk' $5 meters are fine for low voltage use, and most are remarkably accurate for the price. The extra features you get on expensive meters (auto-ranging, true-rms etc.) usually aren't needed or even wanted. Just don't use the supplied leads for measuring high current, as they often have quite high resistance.

Comment: Heck, you can even get usb oscilloscopes for under 40$ these days, yeah they are junk but they are sure a lot better than nothing and great for low speed digital busses like spi and I2c

Comment: I have bought a multimeter